# add a textarea to shipping address

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, orders, shipping-address

I followed this tutorial to add a new field to checkout:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Problem is: as long as it is a `<input type="text" />` everything works. But if I change my input field to a `<textarea>` it won't save.

I highly suspect Magento guys just don't know about textareas...

Well on a serious note, I found code handling textareas but couldn't find code that handles textareas in checkout. Also I didn't find any implementation of a textarea in magento.

Has anyone figured how to do it? (or if it is possible at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to add textarea to the shipping address on checkout. I just added a delivery comment field which is a textarea.

In your LayoutProcessor plugin you should declare the field like this:

```
'delivery_comment' => [
    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
    'config' => [
        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
        'options' => [],
    ],
    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_comment',
    'label' => __('Delivery Comment'),
    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
    'visible' => true,
    'validation' => false,
    'sortOrder' => 250,
]
```

How do you handle the saving of this data to the quote and order models? Did you follow the tutorial?

I think that you need to observe the `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` event and copy the field from quote to order object.

Comment: I was sure I tried this but it seems I have tried everything but this! My problem was the definition of the component. It works now. Thanks!